# [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0 always returns 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The data populates, but `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]` always returns 0. There is only one section in my table. What types of things can cause this behavior?

Comment: try giving it different numbers to see which section returns correct number of rows

Comment: No luck any but 0 return an invalid number error....

Comment: start a loop from 0 to `[tableView numberOfSections]` and NSLog() this statement with loop counter as argument eg. `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]` where i is your loop counter

Comment: Nope no help. Tried a look all non zero numbers return the 2147483647 error.

Comment: just checking...have you implemented the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: data source method. Unless u implement that like proposed by iApple, you wouldnt be able to get the number of rows by calling this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one section always in your table, go with the following coed...

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 1;
    }
```

Or in case your number of sections are depending on datasource, you can return the count of your datasource.

Comment: Hmmm... I am trying to get the number rows in a section, not set the number rows in a section... Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @mdominick - The number of rows in a section is equal to the number of rows you return for a section. Hence you are probably missing the point of this delegate method.

Comment: So yeah what I am doing is [data count]. I also tried hardcoding an actual number (as you do in your sample) and though the method is called the value seems to become 0...

Comment: By default, you have to return 1 as number of section and if you are having grouped data to be display, return number of section as you have number of groups.

Comment: Please check **[data count]**. It might be returning null or 0 and also verify the delegates of UITableview.

Comment: You shouldn't try to get the number of rows in section via your UI as it seems you want to do. As long as you are the data provider of you table view you should get your number of rows from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

Try this. It might help you.